# Create a Custom Notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

How to create custom notification in flutter using `flutter_local_notifications` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) wherein I want use a texttheme and colors of my choice ,and add images and icons to notification

Answer (score 0):

Use this package [awesome_notifications: ^0.6.20](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) for creating customer notification in flutter. This package has many features. That will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For better UI custom notification  `awesome_notifications: ^0.6.20` use this package. Where there is an option for delivering images, sounds, emoticons, best fonts and animated messages in the notification. Which will suit your Application UI.